# Displaying equation on graph (ggplot2)

Tags: r

I'm new to R and using the following codes to plot a graph:

```
p <- ggplot(data = data, aes(x, y, color=group)) +
     geom_smooth(method = "lm", se=FALSE, formula = lineq) + 
     stat_poly_eq(formula = lineq,
               eq.with.lhs = "italic(hat(y))~`=`~",
               aes(label = paste(..eq.label..)), 
               parse = TRUE) +         
     geom_point()
```

when I plot this, the equation currently displays as
y^ = intercept + ax

How can I change the code so that the equation displays with the actual name of the variable?

For example, height^ = intercept + age * x

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like

```
library(ggpmisc)

p <- ggplot(data = data, aes(x = age, y = height, color=group)) +
     geom_smooth(method = "lm", se=FALSE, formula = lineq) + 
     stat_poly_eq(formula  = lineq,
               eq.with.lhs = "italic(height)~`=`~",
               eq.x.rhs    = "~italic(age)",
               aes(label   = paste(..eq.label..)), 
               parse = TRUE) +         
     geom_point()
```